# How can I decide whether to stay as a temp in the hope I'll be hired permanently?

Tags: contracting

I've been working almost 6 months as a temp for a Aerospace company as an administrative assistant. I started working here in August. Two of the managers wanted to get me hired on in January but something happened and they suddenly left the company. They recently hired a new HR manager who I now report to. She told me that because she is new and all the changes, it'll be months before she even considers hiring me.

I'm disappointed at everything that's happened, I love working here but I don't know if it's worth it to keep working here if now I know my chances are slim. How can I make a smart decision - what should I take into account?

Comment: I think that the best thing is searching for another job.

Comment: I've edited to make it less "what should I do?" but it would be worthwhile for you to think about what you'd like someone to tell you **other than what to do next** that would help you make a good decision, then edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Take into account several things:

- First, what is the financial situation? You likely currently have no
  benefits, can you afford to wait to get them?
- Do you like the actual work?
- Do you generally like the working conditions
- How do you feel about your new boss? Does she seem to be someone you
  can work with?
- How much chance is there that she will simply end your temp contract?
  If the chances are high, can you easily find another job?
- What other jobs are available in your local area that you are
  qualified for. Sometimes it is best to stay at a less than optimum
  place if no other decent possibilities exist to move to.

Only you can determine the answers to these questions and the importance you place on them. I personally value good working conditions and coworkers and interesting work over salary. Other people have make different choices.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it like a share that has lost value: The time you spent building trust with the previous managers is (pretty much) gone, as are any promises made by them. You won't ever get these back.

Instead you now work at an aerospace company as a temp admin assistant with a new manager, as you did 6 months ago. Only you have 6 months more experience.

From here, your chances can improve, or they could get worse. They can always swap the manager again in 6 months time.

This was an acceptable position for you 6 months ago. If it's not acceptable anymore, figure out if you can change something about the situation to make it acceptable. If you can, do so. If you can't, look for another job.

Answer (score 0):

I would soldier on while looking for a new job, waiting several months is too vague, and waiting on the convenience of a new HR who may not last long in any case is not something I would do.

So, I would go to HR and tell them I was close to be being made permanent and let them know I don't want to wait a few months with no resolution. Just because previous managers have left does not mean it's a clean slate, their promises made while in that position should still be given due consideration and honoured unless there is a specific reason why not (which does not include a HR persons reluctance to do any work). At the very least I would want a definite timeframe for my case to be reviewed and a decision made.

You can be let go at any minute as a temp, you have nothing to lose. Exert what pressure you can and negotiate from the strongest position you can.